# Apache Netbeans 12 with Java 11 failing to insert auto complete in editor. How to resolve?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I am using apache Netbeans 12 with Java 11 on Macbook Air. Whenever I type java code and choose from suggestion popup it getting erased from editor instead insert.
How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2494

Maybe some of the comments might help you out.